# Regular SQL create table and inherit from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance

How do I, in regular MySQL (NOT PostgreSQL), create a table and in the process inherit from another table all of their schema? Example:

```
create table Person(Age integer not null, Name varchar(123));
create table Student(studyField varchar(155)) INHERITS Person; <--- Error!
create table Worker(profession varchar(5), Person(1, 'anamaste')); <--- Eror!
create table Teacher(teachField varchar(999) references Person(1)); <--- Error!
alter table Student references Person; <--- Error!


Error: SQL error -12101 in function PREPARE
         Syntax error, 'ADD'  assumed missing <-- from the first inheritance example.
```

I am unable to find anything on this. Either I need to have some primary key which I do not want or it is a solution specific for PostgreSQL. Can somebody please guide me to find a solution on **how to create a new table and inherit from another at the same time?**

Comment: MySQL doesn't support inheritance so you cannot do this.

Answer (score -1):

According to @GordonLinoff, there is no way to inherit a schema or table from another schema or table in MySQL. Inheritance in SQL is non-existent.